# Android music player allowing to put a label on each track

Tags: android, music, mp3, id3

I am looking for an Android application having the following features:

- Can play MP3s
- Can assign labels to MP3s: ideally we could choose in which ID3 field they should be saved, or that could be exported easily (e.g. in a CVS with fields: MP3 filename, label). Still ideally, the user should be able to create labels. Labels are strings, e.g. "house".

If possible:

- Can list all MP3s that have been assigned to a given label
- Allows to navigate to any directory and play all tracks located in this directory (like the app [Folder Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.folderplayer))
- Can assign several labels to one track
- Can play FLACs as well
- Is free

Answer (score 1):

Lithium Music Player offers tag editing feature as well as listing according to the tags assigned.

It however does not allow navigation to a directory and playing tracks from a certain folder as you would wish, but you can restrict the content to be played to a specific folder in the SD card.

I am using a free version which I did not get from the market but its charged US$2.00 in my country. Here is the [play store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haramitare.lithiumplayer)

Comment: While this theoretically answers the question, it would be preferable to explain how mentioned tool meets OP requirements.